# Reduce decimal places in parseFloat values in text input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a calculator that I have coded, and it works perfectly well! The only issue I am having is that the parseFloat is pushing out numbers with 12 decimal places into my text input fields. I need no more than 2 decimal places, but for the life of me I cant figure out how to restrict the decimal places.

What would be the best practice to reduce the amount of decimal places in my output? I'm sure it's easy, but I can't pinpoint how to do it.

HTML

```
<p class="title">VET Student Loans Repayment Calculator</p>
<p class="text">Course Cost</p>
  <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input value1" placeholder="0">
    <p class="text">How much do you earn per year?</p>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select onchange="calculateTotals()" name="annualincome" class="input" id="income" placeholder="Your Annual Income">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Your Annual Income</option>
      <option value="0">Below $45,881</option>
      <option value="0.01">$45,881 - $52,973 (1%)</option>
      <option value="0.02">$52,974 - $56,151 (2%)</option>
      <option value="0.025">$56,152 – $59,521 (2.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.03">$59,522 - $ 63,092 (3%)</option>
      <option value="0.035">$63,093 - $66,877 (3.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.04">$66,878 - $70,890 (4%)</option>
      <option value="0.045">$70,891 - $75,144 (4.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.05">$75,145 - $79,652 (5%)</option>
      <option value="0.055">$79,653 - $84,432 (5.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.06">$84,433 - $89,498 (6%)</option>
      <option value="0.065">$89,499 - $94,868 (6.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.07">$94,869 - $100,560 (7%)</option>
      <option value="0.075">$100,561 - $106,593 (7.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.08">$106,594 - $112,989 (8%)</option>
      <option value="0.085">$112,990 - $119,769 (8.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.09">$119,770 - $126,955 (9%)</option>
      <option value="0.095">$126,956 - $134,572 (9.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.10">$134,573 and above (10%)</option>
    </select>
    <p class="text">20% Loading Fee</p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="loading" disabled="disabled" placeholder="0"><br>
    <p class="text">Total VET Student Loan Amount</p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" disabled="disabled" id="result" placeholder="0"><br>
    <p class="text"><br><br>
    Your estimated after tax repayments are; <br><br> Per Year
    </p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" disabled="disabled" id="peryearresult" placeholder="After Tax Repayment - Yearly">
    <p class="text">
    Per Month
    </p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" disabled="disabled" id="permonthresult" placeholder="After Tax Repayment - Monthly">
        <p class="text">
    Per Fortnight
    </p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" disabled="disabled" id="perfortnightresult" placeholder="After Tax Repayment - Fortnightly">
        <p class="text">
    Per Week
    </p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="number" class="input" disabled="disabled" id="perweekresult" placeholder="After Tax Repayment - Weekly">
```

JS

````
            $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
                calculate();
            });

            $('#income').change(function() {
                calculate();
            });

            function calculate(){
                var val1 = parseFloat($('.value1').val());
                var val2 = parseFloat($('.value2').val());
                var val3 = parseFloat($('.value3').val());
                var val4 = parseFloat($('#income').val());
                var sum = val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20);
                $("input#result").val(sum);

                sum = (val1 / 100 * 20);
                $("input#loading").val(sum);

                sum = (val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20)) * val4;
                $("input#peryearresult").val(sum);

                sum = (val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20)) * val4 / 12;
                $("input#permonthresult").val(sum);

                sum = (val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20)) * val4 / 26;
                $("input#perfortnightresult").val(sum);

                sum = (val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20)) * val4 / 52;
                $("input#perweekresult").val(sum);
            }
        });```
````

Answer (score 0):

The `toFixed()` method formats a number using fixed-point notation.

[toFixed() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Answer (score 0):

I found using `Math.round`fixed the issue!

```
sum = Math.round(((val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20)) * val4 / 52) * 100) / 100;
$("input#perweekresult").val(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of `toFixed(decimalnumber)` as shown in below code

```js
 $(function(){
        $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
           calculate();
         });

         $('#income').change(function() {
            calculate();
        });

        function calculate(){
            var val1 = parseFloat($('.value1').val());
            var val2 = parseFloat($('.value2').val());
            var val3 = parseFloat($('.value3').val());
            var val4 = parseFloat($('#income').val());
            var sum = parseFloat(val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20));
            $("input#result").val(parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2));

                sum = (val1 / 100 * 20);
                $("input#loading").val(parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2));

                sum = (val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20)) * val4;
                $("input#peryearresult").val(parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2));

                sum = (val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20)) * val4 / 12;
                $("input#permonthresult").val(parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2));

                sum = (val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20)) * val4 / 26;
                $("input#perfortnightresult").val(parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2));

                sum = (val1 + (val1 / 100 * 20)) * val4 / 52;
                $("input#perweekresult").val(parseFloat(sum).toFixed(2));
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="title">VET Student Loans Repayment Calculator</p>
<p class="text">Course Cost</p>
  <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input value1" placeholder="0">
    <p class="text">How much do you earn per year?</p>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select onchange="calculateTotals()" name="annualincome" class="input" id="income" placeholder="Your Annual Income">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Your Annual Income</option>
      <option value="0">Below $45,881</option>
      <option value="0.01">$45,881 - $52,973 (1%)</option>
      <option value="0.02">$52,974 - $56,151 (2%)</option>
      <option value="0.025">$56,152 – $59,521 (2.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.03">$59,522 - $ 63,092 (3%)</option>
      <option value="0.035">$63,093 - $66,877 (3.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.04">$66,878 - $70,890 (4%)</option>
      <option value="0.045">$70,891 - $75,144 (4.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.05">$75,145 - $79,652 (5%)</option>
      <option value="0.055">$79,653 - $84,432 (5.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.06">$84,433 - $89,498 (6%)</option>
      <option value="0.065">$89,499 - $94,868 (6.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.07">$94,869 - $100,560 (7%)</option>
      <option value="0.075">$100,561 - $106,593 (7.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.08">$106,594 - $112,989 (8%)</option>
      <option value="0.085">$112,990 - $119,769 (8.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.09">$119,770 - $126,955 (9%)</option>
      <option value="0.095">$126,956 - $134,572 (9.5%)</option>
      <option value="0.10">$134,573 and above (10%)</option>
    </select>
    <p class="text">20% Loading Fee</p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="loading" disabled="disabled" placeholder="0"><br>
    <p class="text">Total VET Student Loan Amount</p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" disabled="disabled" id="result" placeholder="0"><br>
    <p class="text"><br><br>
    Your estimated after tax repayments are; <br><br> Per Year
    </p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" disabled="disabled" id="peryearresult" placeholder="After Tax Repayment - Yearly">
    <p class="text">
    Per Month
    </p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" disabled="disabled" id="permonthresult" placeholder="After Tax Repayment - Monthly">
        <p class="text">
    Per Fortnight
    </p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" disabled="disabled" id="perfortnightresult" placeholder="After Tax Repayment - Fortnightly">
        <p class="text">
    Per Week
    </p>
    <span class="prefix">$</span>
    <input type="number" class="input" disabled="disabled" id="perweekresult" placeholder="After Tax Repayment - Weekly">
```